# how can I add button in Textview-android studio layout editor

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-editor

[button"start" is in Textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORL4.png)

How can I do that?

Comment: From your image it looks' below' TextView not 'in'.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take `Button` component. But if you want to take `TextView` then:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/start_btn_bg"
        android:text="start"
        android:paddingHorizontal="30dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"/>
```

You can set background by making the custom drawable.
Below is the custom drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="@color/color_red_error"
    android:centerColor="@color/color_red_error"
    android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

Comment: Hi, i think you can also add your `start_btn_bg` snippet here :)

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to have a button with rounded textView then this is how i do it.  Take note, i am using `com.google.android.material` here to get the fastest result i wanted.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="start"
    app:cornerRadius="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is how it looks like on my IDE.

[image]